# Access Denied while using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to navigate through this site to see the offer available at this address but I get an access denied error. Any recommendations on getting around this?

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome('/chromedriver')
browser.get('https://official.spectrum.com/')

addressSearch = browser.find_element_by_id('street-hero')
addressSearch.send_keys('5214 Wentworth Dr')

zipSearch = browser.find_element_by_id('zip-hero')
zipSearch.send_keys('78413')

submitBtn = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="form-section"]/form/button')
submitBtn.click()
```

Comment: do you have `/chromedriver` at root , is it with the right permission ?

Comment: pls provide the error log, also does it open the browser and load the url?

Comment: Yes I have the full path for the chromedriver added. The script navigates to "official.spectrum.com" adds the address and zip, then clicks the "Shop now" button. Once the "Shop now" button is clicked, it fails to load the next page by giving me this error: "Access Denied You don't have permission to access "http://buy.spectrum.com/store/buyflow/storefront.jsp" on this server.
Reference #18.4f4ccdad.1588173951.34621a2

Answer (score 0):

In general you need to make sure that `chromedriver_path` is 
accessible for the user that is executing the script and with right permissions